# FSA MegaExo crank tensioner bolt, can I use any 12mm bolt?

Tags: crankset

I have a FSA MegaExo (which just came with a bike I bought 2nd hand). As usual the bike needed service because the previous owner did not do anything before selling.
Crank tensioner bolt FSA 12M was stuck, so I had to cut and remove it. 
Would you just look for any 12mm bolt or buy the original one (5euro + shipping)?
Bottom bracket was dead as well, and I realize this is quite expensive because of the strange size of the axle - 19mm. It costs 35 euro
Is it worth buying all this or not really worth for this just generic crankset?

Comment: Aren't FSA bolts self extracting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inferring you have one of the FSA 19mm cranks with a Shimano-style pinch bolt and slot arrangement to secure the left crank to the spindle.

Any 12mm bolt that can make contact with the left crank can do the job of setting the BB preload. Under normal circumstances that bolt does nothing while riding. However, it does have the secondary function of keeping your crank from falling off for a while if the pinch bolts come loose. Maybe a random bolt and some washers would do the same, maybe not.

The 19mm BBs are not the greatest. I do feel like they get a slightly unfair bad rap because usually riders who burn through them also never adjust them. It's somewhat a matter of opinion whether it's worth it to keep 19mm FSA cranks going. New cranks tend to give you a relatively good deal on fresh chainrings, so that's part of it, but making good use of them needs a new chain and cassette.

Comment: yes, the bolt only help you when giving it the right tension, then after there are the 2 other bolt keeping the crank in place and tensioned. Never had problems with shimano or so on.
Unfortunately my only doubt is that it is not worth to buy a totally different and much more expensive BB only to use this crank, but since I have it fitted (Igot it on a bike already like this) with a Hope chainring, I will probably invest in BB and tension bolt and  use it.
I will try and follow your suggestion and see what kind of alternative 12mm bolt I could use
Thanks